# Can I explicitly import an extension method in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3

Given an extension method defined using the `implicit class` syntax:

```
package casa

object MyExtensions:
  implicit class IntOps(val underlying: Int):
    def twice: Int = underlying * 2

  implicit class StringOps(val underlying: String):
    [...]
```

I can explicitly import it and use it with

```
@main def double(): Unit = {
  import casa.MyExtensions.IntOps
  println(s"2 * 2 = ${2.twice}")
}
```

However when I use Scala 3's `extension` syntax:

```
package casa

object MyExtensions:
  extension (underlying: Int)
    def twice: Int = underlying * 2

  extension (underlying: String)
    [...]
```

I seem to have to wildcard-import the extension:

```
@main def double(): Unit = {
  import casa.MyExtensions.*
  println(s"2 * 2 = ${2.twice}")
}
```

Is there a way to explicitly import only a specific extension?

Comment: No AFAIK, you may wrap each `extension` on an `object` so you can have the same behaviour.

Comment: Indeed... it just seems surprisingly quite clunkier than the original syntax. Plus, when the extensions are defined in an OS library, wrapping in an object requires adding intermediate code for every extension!

Comment: You can define the extension methods in a trait and mix them in - so there would be no import needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure in what version this feature appeared or whether it existed always but yes, you can import a single extension method

```
object MyExtensions:
  extension (underlying: Int)
    def twice: Int = underlying * 2

  extension (underlying: String)
    def foo: Unit = ()

def test() =
  import MyExtensions.twice
  2.twice // compiles
  "a".foo // doesn't compile
```

With `import MyExtensions.*` you import all of them.

Tested in Scala 3.2.1.